# How to check if embedded database exists?

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I'd like to use `Spring-Batch` with an embedded `h2` database to save the metadata from the batch jobs.

I just want to always run the database script on each application start, so I don't have to worry about missing database file if I move my application.

But how can I check if the script has to be run? Because if I run it and the DB exists already, I'm getting the following exception:

`org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Table "BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE" already exists`

```
DataSourceInitializer init = new DataSourceInitializer();
init.setDataSource(embeddedDB); //embedded h2 db
ResourceDatabasePopulator populator = new ResourceDatabasePopulator();
populator.addScript(resource); //"classpath:org/springframework/batch/core/schema-h2.sql"
initializer.setDatabasePopulator(populator);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [ResourceDatabasePopulator.setContinueOnError()](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/init/ResourceDatabasePopulator.html#setContinueOnError(boolean)) property

> Flag to indicate that all failures in SQL should be logged but not
>   cause a failure.Defaults to false